# Microsoft SQL Server versus Postgres Spatial

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I currently work with Postgres database with the Spatial component installed is there a difference in spatial functionality between Postgres with Spatial and the latest Microsoft SQL Server version?

Comment: What problems do you have that you think will be solved with SQL Server?

Comment: Our company use at this moment PostGres for building shapes and geo map layers. We use therefor the GeoSpatial modulle within Postgres. The plan is to move to the Microsoft Azure and work with Azure SQL Database.  But i don't know what the impact on functional level.

Comment: You can get Postgres (not PostGres) on Azure as well: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/ (I assume you are referring to [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) when you talk about "geo spatial module2?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are slight difference, basic function are the same (st_distance, st_equal). Postgis have some function that SQL Server doesn't have (like [st_clusterkmeans](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_ClusterKMeans.html)). Sql server function are named `STXXX`, where postgis function are named `ST_XXX`.

So in term of function you'll not be lost, bu in term of SQL, postgres use PLpgSQL where SQL Server use T-SQL. You can see example of sql server [basic request here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Postgres doesn't "use" PL/pgSQL - Postgres (unlike SQL Server) makes a clear distinction between the query language (SQL) and procedural language. Queries (DML, DDL) are written in SQL - stored function can be written in PL/pgSQL (or SQL or Python or JavaScript or ....)

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nameyou're right the term "use" was not appropriate here.